# Tiled Tiff Image Data Issue

Tags: tiff

I am opening a tiled image ([Tiled Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljn1i.jpg)) with Bioformats. Some formats with RGB24 format work, but others are shown incorrectly. With the following code I can get a 8 bit or 16 bit plane to show correctly.

```
bytes = b.imRead.openBytes(b.Coords[coord.Z, coord.C, coord.Z], tilex, tiley, sx, sy);
            if (b.file.EndsWith("tif") || b.file.EndsWith("ndpi"))
            {
                byte[] rb = new byte[strplane * sy];
                Bitmap[] bfs = new Bitmap[3];
                for (int y = 0; y < sy; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < strplane; x++)
                    {
                        rb[((strplane) * y) + x] = bytes[((strplane) * y) + x];
                    }
                }
                Bitmap binf = null;
                if (b.bitsPerPixel == 8)
                {
                    return new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, rb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, rb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                }
                return binf;
            }
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat, bytes, coord, p, littleEndian);
            bm.Stats = Statistics.FromBytes(bm);
            return bm;
```

Attached an image showing the 3 RGB channels of the image.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting of the code I previously provided this worked.

```
byte[] bytesr = b.imRead.openBytes(b.Coords[coord.Z, 0, coord.T], tilex, tiley, sx, sy);
            bool interleaved = b.imRead.isInterleaved();
            if (!interleaved)
            {
                byte[] rb = new byte[strplane * sy];
                byte[] gb = new byte[strplane * sy];
                byte[] bb = new byte[strplane * sy];
                int ind = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < sy; y++)
                {
                    for (int st = 0; st < strplane; st++)
                    {
                        rb[((strplane) * y) + st] = bytesr[((strplane) * y) + st];
                        ind++;
                    }
                }
                byte[] bytes = new byte[ind];
                Array.Copy(bytesr,ind,bytes,0,ind);
                for (int y = 0; y < sy; y++)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    for (int st = 0; st < strplane; st++)
                    {
                        int i = ((strplane) * y) + x;
                        gb[i] = bytes[((strplane) * y) + st];
                        x++;
                    }
                }
                Array.Copy(bytesr, ind * 2, bytes, 0, ind);
                for (int y = 0; y < sy; y++)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    for (int st = 0; st < strplane; st++)
                    {
                        int i = ((strplane) * y) + x;
                        bb[i] = bytes[((strplane) * y) + st];
                        x++;
                    }
                }
                Bitmap[] bms = new Bitmap[3];
                if (b.bitsPerPixel == 8)
                {
                    bms[2] = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, rb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                    bms[1] = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, gb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                    bms[0] = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, bb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                    return Bitmap.RGB8To24(bms);
                }
                else
                {
                    bms[2] = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, rb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                    bms[1] = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, gb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                    bms[0] = new Bitmap(b.file, sx, sy, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, bb, new ZCT(0, 0, 0), p, littleEndian);
                    return Bitmap.RGB16To48(bms);
                }
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).